# Python: error using osmnx during building extraction

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I would like to extract the building layer information from in Haiti using `osmnx`. I works for different cities it does not in the case of

```
import osmnx as ox
place_name = "Port-au-Prince"
buildings = ox.buildings_from_place(place_name)
```

I get the following error

`TypeError: Geometry must be a shapely Polygon or MultiPolygon`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an internal bug of osmnx. "Port-au-Prince" is mapped in OSM as a [node](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). This node is the [first result when searching for "Port-au-Prince" in Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Port-au-Prince) (a geocoder). osmnx seems to expect an area instead, i.e. an [administrative boundary relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative). Such a relation comes second and third in Nominatim. osmnx seems to fail if it finds a node as first search result. Create an upstream bug report for osmnx.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: You can report osmnx bugs at https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/new. However there are already several issues with the error message from your question. See for example https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/207 and other issues referenced from there.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/16 for a comprehensive discussion of this issue and how to resolve it in your query.

Per the OSMnx documentation:

> The query must be geocodable and OSM must have polygon boundaries for the geocode result. If OSM does not have a polygon for this place, you can instead get its street network using the graph_from_address function, which geocodes the place name to a point and gets the network within some distance of that point. Alternatively, you might try to vary the which_result parameter to use a different geocode result. For example, the first geocode result (ie, the default) might resolve to a point geometry, but the second geocode result for this query might resolve to a polygon, in which case you can use graph_from_place with which_result=2.